# Error: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28'

Tags: android, android-studio, synchronization

When I sync my project in build.gradle(Project: Allo) I see this error

> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28'in: C:\Users\hacker\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Config:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.allo"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 rc2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0 rc2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

[image: and this is the image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read [**`Set Up the Android P SDK`**](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk).

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-P'

defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 'P'
}
```

> For the best development experience with the Android P Preview SDK, we
>   recommend that you install the latest Android Studio 3.2 canary.

You should install the Android P Preview SDK as follows:

- Click **Tools > SDK Manager**.
- In the SDK Platforms tab, select **Android P Preview**.
- In the SDK Tools tab, select **Android SDK Build-Tools 28-rc2** (or
  higher).
- Click OK to begin install.

Comment: @SamuelRobert Indeed.

Comment: Thanks, but how I can install android Studio 3.2 canary?

Comment: I had to set compileSdkVersion to 'android-P' and targetSdkVersion to 28.

Answer (score 4):

I got the error "Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28'", None of the solutions above solved my issue.

Here's what caused my problem:

in the project gradle.build I added a user defined extension key value as such:

```
ext {
    ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=28
}
```

Then in the module gradle.build I then referenced this value as such:

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION
   ...
```

That's what causes the error!!  What I did to correct the issue was to code it this way:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion Integer.valueOf(rootProject.ext.ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK_VERSION)
```

In other words, compileSdkVerion wants an interger, not a string.  The same it true with minSdkVerion, targetSdkVersion and versionCode in your gradle script.

I don't know if that's the problem that the above posters were experiencing, but that at least one way in which that error message can occur.  And by the way, I could use support libraries 28.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Replace these two dependencies

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 rc2'
>
> implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0 rc2'

with these

> implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
>
> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'